# Meaning of "Working to a brief"

Tags: meaning, idioms, informal-language

What does the following sentence mean:

"I like not working to a brief"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "work to a brief" is a mainly British English expression meaning to work according to instructions.

> NOUN
>   1 British
>   A set of instructions given to a person about a job or
>   task.
>
> ‘his brief is to turn round the county's fortunes’

[Brief (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brief)

Comment: Alternatively, it could mean something along the lines of "I appreciate the fact that i don't have to follow specific instructions."

Comment: Thanks, Hellion, for explaining the expression in detail.